# How can i speed up this "mini-git" class?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I want to build Git class where i can store `int` values (let's call them files). Number of files that are going to be stored passed to constructor of class with `filesCount`.  I'll need an `void Update(int fileNumber, int value)` method, `int Commit()` method that saves current state of files and returns `commitNumber` (the number of times method was called minus 1). And last but not least `int Checkout(int fileNumber, int commitNumber)` pretty much self-explanatory. 
I need this class to be fast and memory efficient. My current solution is too slow with `int Checkout(int commitNumber, int fileNumber)` . 
Here it is :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

namespace GitTask
{
    public class Git
    {
        int[] Files { get; set; }
        Dictionary<int[], List<int>> Commits { get; set; }
        int CommitsCount { get; set; }

        public Git(int filesCount)
        {
            Files = new int[filesCount];
            Commits = new Dictionary<int[], List<int>>(new MyEqualityComparer());
        }

        public void Update(int fileNumber, int value)
        {
            Files[fileNumber] = value;
        }

        public int Commit()
        {
            var temp = new int[Files.Count()];
            Array.Copy(Files, temp, Files.Count());
            if (Commits.ContainsKey(temp))
            {
                Commits[temp].Add(CommitsCount);
            }
            else
            {
                Commits[temp] = new List<int>(new int[] { CommitsCount });
            }
            CommitsCount++;
            return CommitsCount - 1;
        }

        public int Checkout(int commitNumber, int fileNumber)
        {
            if (commitNumber >= CommitsCount)
                throw new ArgumentException();
            else
            {
                var k = Commits.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.BinarySearch(commitNumber) > -1).Key;
                return k[fileNumber];
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
    {
        public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
        {
            if (x.Length != y.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                if (x[i] != y[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
        {
            int result = 17;
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++)
            {
                result = result * 23 + obj[i];
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I expect you to come up with tips on speeding it up or creating new kind of storing files as this one (using `Dictionary<int[], List<int>)` might already be as fast as it can be.

A little explanation to `int Commit()` method and general purpose of using this dictionary. As i need to store numbers i decided to store only unique arrays  in my dictionary and use them as a key and value is a `List<int>` that contains commit numbers that response to that array of numbers so i can store unique array only one time and have commit numbers.

Comment: This sounds like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RufusL should i delete this question right now?

Comment: Well, you haven't actually asked a question. Where are your benchmark tests? How fast do you expect it to run? Where is the bottleneck? Remember, stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. It's for answering specific programming questions.

Comment: @RufusL well i said that ```Checkout(int commitNumber, int fileNumber)``` is too slow for now. I can't provide any tests as it is a task at my college and tests are hidden. I just can't pass one last test that is called "Checkout method too slow". I feel like storing files is not as efficient as it should be as i use binary search on values of dictionary.

Comment: You're doing a linear search (with `FirstOrDefault`) through the `KeyValuePair<int[], List<int>>` items and calling `BinarySearch` on each `List<int>` until one binary search succeeds (or all if it never does). The key of the dictionary should be the commit number returned from the `Commit` method.

Comment: @madreflection i use ```KeyValuePair<int[], List<int>>``` because this way i can store only unique arrays of files, you can see that in ```int Commit()``` method. If i would store all arrays it would be a memory limit.

Comment: You can still do that check without using the array as the key. Your choice of key is causing the performance problem. The tests probably are using very large arrays to test how efficient your lookup is. Move that load to the `Commit` method. `Checkout` doesn't care what's unique: "Go give me commit number N".

Comment: What do the dictionary key and value represent?

Comment: @madreflection so how should i store files then? I didn't clearly understand your idea as you only proposed to change key to commit number but didn't say a thing about storing fiels and changing value of dictionary.

Comment: @RufusL key represents set of files, value represents commit numbers that correspond to that files

Comment: In Git, even if all the files and the author are the same, the timestamp and/or the parent(s) will be different, so it'll get a different hash and no two commits will ever be the same. The key should be the commit number, and the value should be the "files". The idea that multiple commits with the same "files" should be considered the same thing is not Git-like.

Comment: @madreflection well it seems like this task is not supposed to be a "git" copy but just some efficient coding task.

Comment: Is it a requirement that committing the same set of "files" should be tracked in this way? It appears to be a detail of your implementation and not part of the public interface. This looks to me like a case of premature optimization.

Comment: @madreflection no it's not a requierment. It's just the way that i solved memory limit exception that i had when i used to store all the files. Ever since i decided to store only unique sets of files

Comment: You can still "merge" identical lists, just don't *key* on it. Do that in `Commit` where the load is expected to be. Wrap the "files" in an object that includes a hash so you can quickly scan for possible duplicates. `Checkout` will take the commit number and had it to the dictionary, which will go right to it and give you the "files".

Comment: @madreflection okay, i see your idea. Let me try it. I'll say if it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199535/discussion-between-jubick-and-madreflection).